# Is it possible to use async.waterfall or async.series with dynamically generated functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql, async.js

The use case here is I am using mysql and I want to allow writing a function:
- begin a transaction
- execute some sql statements
- commit transaction
If error at any time:
- rollback transaction

This works well using async.waterfall, with code like this:

```js
    async.waterfall([
        // start transaction (i.e. "begin;")
        function(callback) {
            conn.beginTransaction(function(err) {
                callback(err);
            })
        },
        // step 1: create temp table which will contain our changed values
        function(callback) {
            conn.query(createTempTableQuery, null, function(err, result) {
                callback(err);
            });
        },
        // step 2: insert the changed values into our temp table
        function(callback) {
            conn.query(populateTempTableQuery, [populateTempTableColumns, populateTempTableValues], function(err, result) {
                callback(err);
            });
        },
        // step 3: run some sql update statement
        function(callback) {
            conn.query(updateSqlQuery, updateSqlValues, function(err, result) {
                callback(err);
            });
        },
        // finally, commit our changes
        function(callback) {
            conn.commit(function(err) {
                callback(err);
            });
        }
    ], function(err) {
        // if we hit an error at any step we need to rollback the transaction:
        if (err) {
            conn.rollback(function() { 
                logger.warn("Rolling back changes");
                res.status(400).json({ message: "Unable to edit, Error: " + err });
            });
        }
        else {
            res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully made edits." });
        }
    });
```

This works well, but I am wondering if there is a way not to have to write each function like:

```js
conn.query(populateTempTableQuery, [populateTempTableColumns, populateTempTableValues], function(err, result) {
   callback(err);
});
```

every single time. Ideally, I'd want to have some wrapper function that I can give a set of sql statements, and then async runs them one by one between a begin/commit command.

Basically, is it possible to write something like:

```js
function sqltransaction(sqlStatements, callback) {
// statements is an array of sql queries and values e.g.
// [{ query: "SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = ?", values: ["Peter"] },{ query: "SELECT accessLevel FROM permissions WHERE name = ?", values: ["Paul"] },{ query: "UPDATE users SET status = ? WHERE name = ?", values: ["DISABLED","David"] }]

// async accepts an array of functions, so we can do something like
var functionsArray = [async.constant(sqlStatements), beginTransaction];

for (var i = 0; i < sqlStatements.length; i++) {
  var args = ["conn","i","sqlStatements","results","callback"];
  var code = "conn.query(sqlStatements[i].query, sqlStatements[i].values, function(err, result) {results[i]=result;callback(err,sqlStatements,results);});"
  var sqlfunction = new Function(args, code);
  functionsArray.push(sqlfunction(conn,i,sqlStatements,results,callback))
}

async.waterfall(functionsArray, function(err, result) {
// etc
})
```

The code I have is more or less the above, but I hit errors where callback is not defined (I guess the async.waterfall callback only gets defined when the waterfall has already started).

Either what I am trying to do is not possible, or I am going about this totally wrong. Which is it?

Comment: Yes of course a wrapper is possible, just use a closure. Do not try to build functions from strings.

Comment: If you would just use `callback` instead of the three-line equivalent `function(err, result) {
                callback(err);
            }` it doesn't actually look that bad